# pandas conditional and not

Tags: python, pandas

I do select parts of my dataframe for fitting using a mask:

```
mask = (data.conc == 50) & (data.id_exp == 'Pxxx')
```

During the fit I found a probable outlier and would like to do something like

```
mask = (data.conc == 50) & (data.id_exp == 'P049V208') and not (data.ratio == 10 & data.salt_concentration == 50)
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&` (instead of `and`) to perform element-wise bitwise-and, and use `~` (instead of `not`) to invert the boolean mask.

```
mask = ((data.conc == 50) 
        & (data.id_exp == 'P049V208') 
        & ~((data.ratio == 10) & (data.salt_concentration == 50)))
```

Per the rules of Python, `and` and `not` always attempt to reduce the expression to a boolean value. Since you want boolean *arrays*, not boolean scalars, use `&` and `~` instead.

Comment: I have to do `mask = ((data.conc == 50) & (data.id_exp == 'P049V208')   & ~((data.ratio == 10) & (data.salt_concentration == 50)))` in order to get it to work